# How can you play a video with multiple alternate audio tracks on iOS devices?

Tags: ios

I have a video file with multiple alternate audio tracks (different languages). In Flash, using OSMF, the client can be given the option to select between the different audio tracks. How can I get the same ability on an iOS device? Can the native player handle this?

Thanks,
Apurva

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately you can't play flash on iOS. Native player can't play different audio tracks.**

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the audio tracks from the video into separate files, you can play the video and the audio with separate players (MPMoviePlayerController and AVAudioPlayer, respectively) in parallel. Of course, you have to do some programming to play audio and video synchronously.